# Python Subprocess including variables

Tags: python, subprocess

So this is my current code that I am using. I am setting up an automated password changer for a friend but I am stuck on this last part and can't find the answer anywhere. I am trying to run the final command that will change the password from the python script (admin priveleges are alrdy sorted out). I need to figure out how to input the "variable" which will be random, into the subprocess.call command as well as the other stuff.

```
import subprocess

password = 123456

subprocess.call("net user Chris "+ password, shell = False)



**Error:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\Password Rotation\PasswordChange.py", line 5, 
in <module>
subprocess.call("net user Chris "+ password, shell = False)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
password = 123456
"net user Chris "+ password
```

^^ This won't work because you set `password` to an integer.  Since Python is strongly typed, it won't coerce an integer to a string for you... you have to be explicit and convert it yourself.

However, you probably want to use a string for your password anyways:

```
password = '123456'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
password = "123456"
```

Would do the job

Comment: It flags it as an error whenever I try to run it though

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to include a variable in the subprocesses call, you can do just use the quotation marks as the previous answer suggested:

```
import subprocess

password = "123456"

variable = "include this text too in the subprocesses command" + password

subprocess.call(variable, shell = False)
```